# Would a Question About Dealing With Customers Be Considered On-Topic Here?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-topic

If this Programmers SE question were asked on Project Management SE, would it be considered on-topic?  If this question were asked here, should it be closed?

[How Are We Supposed To Deal With Customers Who Don't Give a Damn?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59889/how-are-we-supposed-to-deal-with-customers-who-dont-give-a-damn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be closed. Dealing with clients is an important part of project management job. Even if we talk about small projects where there's no separate PM, it still belongs to the domain.

After all the question would require only a single tiny adjustment and you wouldn't guess whether it was asked by a developer or a PM.

Comment: Do you feel the [FAQ](http://pm.stackexchange.com/faq) properly addresses this?  Should customer issues be added to the list of topics?  It's important to continue to define the boundaries for what is on-topic and off-topic to set boundaries, both to protect what we believe to be on-topic as well as to keep out things we know are definitely off-topic.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the FAQ to add customer relations.